# Bind Node.js app from Port to Web Address

Tags: apache, redirect, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a nodejs app installed over at /home/username/public_html/OS.js and by running `$ node osjs run` on ssh it starts a server over at http://localhost:5000

After opening the 5000 port on FirewallD, when I go to localhost:5000 I can access the app, but when I go to https://website.com/OS.js/ , I'm not able to access it.

So, I would like to ask for some guidance on how to bind a port to a web address page folder, so it redirects the port to my website. I have both Webmin and Virtalmin installed, is it easier to setup over webmin or ssh?

I know I have to configure a Reverse-Proxy similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName osjs.domain.no
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm a bit lost on where and how to do this. I'm running a CentOS 7.5 cloud server with apache web server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there a typo? you started node at port 5000 but proxy is at 8000?

Comment: Hi, that reverse-proxy is an example